# I get this error when I run python manage.py

Tags: python, django

So I am working with Django. After setting up my URLs in both applications, I get this error when I run `python manage.py migrate`:

> "file "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site
>   packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 542, in url_patterns raise
>   ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'alerts.urls' does not appear to have any
>   patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue
>   is probably caused by a circular import".

However, when I comment out include in my `alerts.urls` file it works fine. How can I fix this? I have attached my `urls.py` files.

This is my `accounts.urls` file:

```
from django.urls import path from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name ='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name ='logout'), 
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name ='signup'), 
]
```

This is my main alerts `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include,path
from django.urls import path,include from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('test/', views.TestPage.as_view(), name="test"), 
    path('thanks/', views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name="thanks"), 
    path('accounts/', include("accounts.urls", namespace="accounts")), 
    path('accounts/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

Comment: well what's in `alerts.urls`? Since this is the one that the error message says has a problem in it.

Comment: this is whats in the alerts.urls                                                         from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include,path
from django.urls import path,include from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('test/', views.TestPage.as_view(), name="test"), 
    path('thanks/', views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name="thanks"), 
    path('accounts/', include("accounts.urls", namespace="accounts")), 
    path('accounts/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]

Comment: are you sure that's the correct URLConf? Looks suspiciously like your root one to me, I presume `alerts.urls` is in one of your apps and is included in another URLConf? You haven't actually showed us where it is included.

Comment: when i check in the settings, alerts.url is my root_urlConf

Comment: i am actually confused here because i am new to django. what other URLConf you talking about

Comment: Never mind, I didn't realise alerts was the root one. Thought it was included from another one.

Comment: Is there a way you can show me to resolve this error?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see anything obviously wrong. Without seeing your entire project it's hard to know what the problem is. (And I'm very far from a Django expert.) I'm only going off the error message - there are clearly URL patterns in that module, so it says it could be an issue with circular imports. Do you think you have any circular imports anywhere? (Like 2 files which each import from the other.)